Spring Boot with Redis caching not working as expected in Docker environment
I'm experiencing an issue with my Spring Boot application using Redis for caching when running in a Docker environment. Here's the situation:

Project setup:

Spring Boot and Java application with Redis for caching
Cache TTL set to 10 minutes
Using Docker Compose to run the application, Redis


Behavior:

When running in IntelliJ IDEA:

The application works as expected
Database is queried only once, then the cache is used


When running in Docker:

The application is significantly slower
Logs show frequent database queries


When manually testing with Postman, making one request at a time to the Docker environment:

Redis caching appears to be working correctly




Relevant code:


Redis Configuration:
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10L))
                .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));

        return RedisCacheManager
                .builder(connectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(cacheConfig)
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
    }
}

Cached method:
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "userCache", key = "#id + ':profile'", cacheManager = "cacheManager")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserResponse getUserProfile(Long id) {
    log.debug("getUserProfile method called with id: {}", id);
    User findUser = userRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(ErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND));
    return UserResponse.builder()
            .nickname(findUser.getNickname())
            .email(findUser.getEmail())
            .role(findUser.getRole().name())
            .picture(findUser.getPicture())
            .build();
}

application.yml:
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        format_sql: true
  data:
    redis:
      host: redis
      port: 6379
  profiles:
    include: oauth

logging.level:
  org.hibernate.SQL: debug
  com.yoonji.dockermaster: debug

Docker Compose:
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: dockermaster
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - redis


Question:

What could be causing this caching issue in the Docker environment, and how can I resolve it to ensure the cache is working as expected for all scenarios, not just when making individual requests?
If there’s any additional code or specifics you’d like me to check related to your issue, please let me know. Since this is my first time using Docker, more detailed guidance would be appreciated
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
